# Oracle SQL query to Get records less than SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has the following data

```html
HEADER_ID  MONTH     YEAR
12078        8       2026
12079        3       2024
12080        10      2022
12081        4       2026
```

MONTH and YEAR are VARCHAR columns. I need a query to get the records which are not less than SYSDATE(Month and Year).

**Example:** The current SYSDATE month and Year is 12, 2022. The query result should have only Header_IDs 12078,12079,12081.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried and describe the issue you've faced: error messages, unexpected result etc. Stackoverflow is not a free codewriting service. It's just a  simple `where` clause

Answer (score 1):

Convert your month/year columns to a date and then compare:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE(year || '-' || month, 'YYYY-MM') >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

Alternatively, you can compare the component parts:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  year > EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
OR     (   year  =  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
       AND month >= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) )
```

*However, you should consider changing your table from `year` and `month` numeric columns to a single `year_month` column with the `DATE` data type with a check constraint `CHECK ( year_month = TRUNC( year_month, 'MM' ) )` to constrain it to always be midnight of the first day of the month.*